# Closing the popup opened using windows.open

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

As the showmodal dialog has been removed from Chrome (post update 37), I am trying to use window.open as an replacement but facing few issues.

Step1 : Consider a web Application 1 where Page1.aspx is opened and when an hyperlink on it is clicked, it opens another Page2.aspx which is part of another web application 2 using window.open.

```
popup = window.open(URL, "_self", settings);
```

Step2 : In Page 2.aspx, there is a cancel button which when clicked , calls Page3.aspx of Application 1 and in this Page3.aspx, we are trying to close Page2.aspx as the cancel button has been clicked. We have tried popup.close(),window.close() and window.parent.close() in the closeWindow function of Page3.aspx

```
<body class="browserbodyClass"  onload="closeWindow();">
```

However, it does not work.

Comment: would you post some code?

Comment: You can use close() to close your window. Go through this link https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_close.asp

Comment: @AbhayDixit Tried but does not work as here we have 2 different web applications.

Comment: @smnbbrv I have edited the details to include some code. Let me know if you need more info.